# How do I reliably invoke clipboard copy/paste actions in other apps without messing with input queue

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard

A while ago I wrote a simple app, which surrounds selected text in any input field in any application with some unicode symbols when user presses some hotkey. Basically, app's logic is as follows:

- Register global hotkey.
- Hotkey fired, now set clipboard monitor and invoke clipboard copy to see if some text was selected.
- If clipboard has changed and now contains text, surround said text with symbols and then invoke clipboard paste, so input field will be updated with modified text.

The problem is, I can't get copy/paste functionality from other apps in a reliable way. What I have tried to date:

1. If I send WM_COPY/WM_PASTE, it's more often ignored than not, depending on the application.
2. If I use SendInput, keybd_event or any other keyboard-messing stuff to press/unpress usual clipboard hotkeys, it will often tamper with user-pressed keys: copy/paste uses control or shift, which are also quite popular for all generic hotkeys in all apps, my app included.
3. If I use Journal Hook to directly inject keyboard messages into system input queue, sometimes it will work fine, and sometimes weird glitches will occur. Also, other applications may be using JournalHook for themselves, and that will mess my app badly. Not to mention that default security policies make journal hook hard to use.
4. I've been trying to get/set text in the input fields using Windows UI automation instead of clipboard magic, but it rarely works.

So, if you know other ways to make other applications reliably use copy/paste functionality, or can even devise entirely different approach, I'd really appreciate you telling me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it seems that I could only find more or less reliable way of invoking copy-paste without SendInput or journal hook, but I have to deal with it :-) So here it is, in case someone find it useful:

1. Remember and reset keyboard modifiers via AttachThreadInput(yourAppThreadId, targetAppThreadId) + SetKeyboardState(keyStateWithoutKeyboardModifiers).
2. Set Ctrl key modifier via SetKeyboardState(keyStateWithControl) for Ctrl+C/V hotkey.
3. Then PostMessage to focused control handle with WM_KEYDOWN message for C or V key, whether you want it to copy or paste.
4. Call Thread.CurrentThread.Join(20) to let other app process messages — and that's the most retarded moment in the whole deal, since I couldn't find the sure way to know when other app will have empty message queue.
5. Restore remembered keyboard modifiers.

Also, every time you do SetKeyboardState, call SetForegroundWindow(focusedControlHandle) and SetFocus(focusedControlHandle) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach isn't that bad, maybe you can start with WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD so you can monitor the clipboard. A nice sample code can be found [here](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx).

Next I'd take a look at [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28VS.80%29.aspx) - Attention: Flush, Buffer, etc. Use this to send ctrl+c/v instead of a windows message! You should get a notification from your monitor if it worked.
Now I'd use the [Cliboard class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) to maniplulate the Data and paste it back.

Comment: Thank you, I test clipboard for changes with GetClipboardSequenceNumber polling. Manipulating clipboard isn't difficult, the main reason I wrote this stuff was hack-ish feeling of all methods which are meddling with input queue. I can easily send Ctrl+C to other app, sure, but if user is pressing Shift+somekey at the same time, I have to remove shift from local thread input queue in order for Ctrl+C to work, and afterwards return Shift back in the queue. If user actually depressed Shift in between these operations, it will cause a sticky key. That's the main reason for using Journal Hook.